# Pagination laravel passing data with GET

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have a filter for example example.com/mypage?page=2&name=Alex

And I have a lot of data with this name and the limit on pagination is 15. My problem is this. When I make the filter everything it's ok because when I press a button i'm sending with GET the values, and the first page it looks good, but when I press for the page 2 on laravel pagination the parameters are removed and it looks like example.com/mypage?page=2. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append additional parameters as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#displaying-pagination-results)

```
$users->appends(['name' => 'Alex'])->links();
```